# catch SQLRecoverableException in spring boot and jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring boot v2.6.7 and jdbc template
this is my function in service:

```
@Override
    public List<Invoice> getByDate(String date_debut, String date_fin) {
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_BY_DATE, ((rs, rowNum) -> {
                return new Invoice(
                        rs.getString("CUST_CODE"),
                        rs.getString("CUST_NAME"),
                        rs.getString("CUST_ADDR1"), 
            }), date_debut, date_fin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I am in catch");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the problem is when the database server is off i get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=w52a0lyvRo6f+Jqqks8haw==)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:872) ~[ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]    
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:677) ~[ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1039) ~[ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:90) ~[ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]     
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:728) ~[ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:649) ~[ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19].
```

But i get the message "I am in catch" which is in catch block. the question is how can i catch java.sql.SQLRecoverableException exception. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

As per [SQLRecoverableException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLRecoverableException.html#:%7E:text=public%20class%20SQLRecoverableException%20extends%20SQLException%20The%20subclass%20of,case%20of%20a%20distributed%20transaction%2C%20the%20transaction%20branch.), its subtype of `Exception` so in case of `SQLRecoverableException`, control will always goes to `Exception` block which you have defined. ( and it will print "I am in catch").

If you want to specifically catch SQLRecoverableException, then you can do something like,

```
@Override
    public List<Invoice> getByDate(String date_debut, String date_fin) {
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_BY_DATE, ((rs, rowNum) -> {
                return new Invoice(
                        rs.getString("CUST_CODE"),
                        rs.getString("CUST_NAME"),
                        rs.getString("CUST_ADDR1"), 
            }), date_debut, date_fin);
        }catch (SQLRecoverableException e) {
            System.out.println("I am in SQLRecoverableException block");
            return null; // either return or do something else 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I am in catch");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ashish Patil thank you for the answer, I too thought it was the case. Which amazes me why the server crash as like the SQLRecoverableException is not catched